# ActiveMQ Artemis upgrade question: HornetQ to Artemis 2.0

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis, hornetq

I have been upgrading an old HornetQ project to Artemis and I ran into some issues with the `JMSServerControl`. My original code looked like this.

```java
final ObjectName on = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getJMSServerObjectName();
final JMSServerControl sControl = jmxConnectorFactory.newProxyInstance( mbsc, on, JMSServerControl.class, false );
final boolean success = sControl.createQueue( canonicalName, jndiBinding );
```

I actually upgraded to ActiveMQ Artemis 1.3 first where this code still works. I am planning on going to 2.15.0 eventually, but I just wasn't sure what other things may have been deprecated so I took a smaller jump to 2.0. The above code broke when I moved to 2.0 so I am using the following.

```java
final ObjectName on = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getActiveMQServerObjectName();
final ActiveMQServerControl sControl = jmxConnectorFactory.newProxyInstance( mbsc, on, ActiveMQServerControl.class, false );
...
```

Now `createQueue` has been deprecated. Any suggestion of what I could use instead to get the same behavior?

Comment: I actually upgraded to Artemis 1.3 first where this code still works. I am planning on going to 2.15 eventually I just wasn't sure what other things may have been deprecated so I took a smaller jump.   This was the method in question. final boolean success = sControl.createQueue( canonicalName, jndiBinding ); I guess I don't need the jndiBinding and the boolean flag was removed

Comment: I'm still not clear on what exactly you mean by "the same behavior"? A number of semantics have changed from HornetQ to ActiveMQ Artemis 2.x. Please clarify exactly what behavior you need. Also, is there a particular reason you can't use one of the non-deprecated `createQueue` methods on `ActiveMQServerControl`?

Comment: Ok. I see your point. I will work on this a little bit more and see what I get, just have to think about it a little differently.  I see ActiveMQServerControl.createQueue( s, s1, s2 ) and some  variations of it. What is the address that this is referring to?  createQueue(String address, String name). The createQueues from other libraries seem to not be consistent to each other. Was trying to figure out how to use this one by looking at for example session.createqueue but it is different. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one of the non-deprecated `createQueue` methods, i.e.:

- `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.ActiveMQServerControlImpl#createQueue(java.lang.String)`
- `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.ActiveMQServerControlImpl#createQueue(java.lang.String, boolean)`

For example:

```java
final ObjectName on = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getActiveMQServerObjectName();
final ActiveMQServerControl sControl = jmxConnectorFactory.newProxyInstance( mbsc, on, ActiveMQServerControl.class, false );
sControl.createQueue(new QueueConfiguration(canonicalName).setRoutingType(RoutingType.ANYCAST).toJSON());
```

This code will create a core queue and a core address with the same name (i.e. `canonicalName`) using the `ANYCAST` routing-type. This will provide the semantics equivalent to a JMS queue. I recommend you read [the chapter from the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html) about JMS-to-core mapping. That will help you understand more about what configuration you need for the core resources to get the semantics you want for your JMS clients.

Comment: So actually that was my issue, SessionContext contains QueueConfiguration but ActiveMQServerControl does not. Instead it uses a string called address and then maybe a name string after that. createQueue(String address, String name). What is that address it is asking for, it is not really in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not following. What do you mean that, "SessionContext contains QueueConfiguration but ActiveMQServerControl does not"? If you're using `ActiveMQServerControl` the only non-deprecated `createQueue` methods are the ones I listed (which take a `String` and a `String` & `boolean`). Please clarify what class you're using with `createQueue(String address, String name)`. To be clear, I'm referring to Artemis 2.15.0.